# Does Julia have dot product in BLAS?

Tags: julia, blas

I'm trying to speed up dot product in Julia. But I can't find BLAS function for dot product.

My current solution is:

```
X = rand(5,1);
Y = rand(5,1);
res = BLAS.gemm('T','N', X, Y);
res[1]
```

I was wondering whether we have a more simple function for dot product in BLAS in Julia. Like `BLAS.dot(X,Y)`.

Comment: Do you mean something like [LinearAlgebra.BLAS.dotu](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/index.html#LinearAlgebra.BLAS.dotu)?

Comment: Yes, but LinearAlgebra seems don't have this function.

Comment: Perhaps you could add more to your original post to describe your difficulty using it.... Or maybe ask a new question.

Answer (score 6):

`LinearAlgebra.BLAS.dotu` is the BLAS1 dot product, but it won't be faster than the Julia built-in. The Julia generic functions for BLAS1 and BLAS2 routines pretty much match OpenBLAS in performance. BLAS3 routines (matrix multiplication) are more in-depth and are faster in OpenBLAS.

Answer (score 2):

There is the
[dot](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/index.html#LinearAlgebra.dot) function:

> For any iterable containers `x` and `y` (including arrays of any
>   dimension) of numbers (or any element type for which dot is defined),
>   compute the dot product (or inner product or scalar product), i.e. the
>   sum of `dot(x[i],y[i])`, as if they were vectors.
>
> `x ⋅ y` (where `⋅` can be typed by tab-completing `\cdot` in the REPL) is a
>   synonym for `dot(x, y)`.

It seems faster than the gemm BLAS call:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using BenchmarkTools
n = 10000
x = rand(n, 1);
y = rand(n, 1);
@btime(BLAS.gemm('T','N', x, y))
  19.212 μs (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
@btime(x ⋅ y)
  1.536 μs (1 allocation: 16 bytes)

versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.0.3
Commit 099e826241* (2018-12-18 01:34 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-suse-linux)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```